# Superset partion graph type order by

Tags: apache-superset

We are creating several charts in superset and with the partition type chart the ORDER BY seems to be hard coded and we cannot change it. The goal is too have the months on the left in the correct order (the column in this case is `Month`). When run in sql lab it works in correct order but in the chart view we cannot change the ordering

Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the dates on the right here?

I work with superset and I have experienced this limitation that does appear to be hard-coded into the ordering once a chart is made.
 I would suggest if it wasn't too much hassle to add another column to your database of the text value and follow the patter of;

WHERE "Month" = 'January' SET "OrderingColumn" = 'A' 
WHERE "Month" = 'February' SET "OrderingColumn" = 'B'

etc etc

Then in your charts you can try: ORDER BY "OrderingColumn"

It is a bit of an inconvenience but if you are able to manipulate your data by changing tables or views this seems to be a solution you could use.

I hope this may be useful even to change the way of approaching the problem.